# For Loop Iteration in Apex

Tags: apex, vs-code

I wrote code for inserting 6 contacts on iteration basics. I got error unexpected token 'public'.Please help me, I can't find the error in this code.

```
public class ContactHandler
{
    public void List<Contact> getContacts() {
        List<Contact> contactlist = new List<Contact>;
        for ( Integer count = 1; count<=5; count++) {
            contactlist.LastName = ('Richie' + count);
            contactlist.Phone = 9876543210;
        }

    }
    Insert contactlist;
    return contactlist;
}
ContactHandler ContactObject = new ContactHandler();
ContactObject.getContacts();
```

How to set the values for sobjects using forloop.

Comment: looks like you're executing all the lines from developer console, usually you create apex class then invoke the call from developer console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instantiate a new contact object and add values to it and add it to the list like below

Check [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_list_sobject.htm) link

```
for ( Integer count = 1; count<=5; count++) {
            contact eachContact = new contact();

            eachContact.LastName = ('Richie' + count);
            eachContact.Phone = 9876543210;
           contactlist.add(eachContact); 
        }
insert contactlist;
```

As pointed out by nbrown Added answer for the comments part: [Phonenumber](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm) field is alpha numeric so put it in quotes.

```
eachContact.Phone = '9876543210';
```

Comment: Thanks @RedDevil. Now, its working. But, I got illegal integer error for eachContact.phone = 9875475668; and when I change it as eachContact.phone='9875475668' ;  it accepted. What is the difference between these codes.

Comment: @Richie, phone number fields in Salesforce are not treated as a number data type, they are strings because they could have leading zeroes and alpha characters in them. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/field_types.htm

Comment: Thanks Brown.Now, I am clear.

Comment: @Richie - you may want to mark this as correct answer for the benefit of community. no pressure though